# How to display a firebases value into text view in a fragment?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing some trouble here! 
* I cannot display a data/value that is retrieve from the Firebase into a textview in a fragment?*

Interface

[Interface Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuknd.png)

The money that retrieve from Firebase should appear in here(HIGHLIGHTED text view) , BUT it is empty.
Thus I also tried in Textview (at the middle), also no working...

Firebase Screenshot

[image: Firebase Table]

User.kt

```
package com.example.fireauth.ui.Data

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties

@IgnoreExtraProperties

data class user(var id: String? ="",
                var name: String? =" ",
                var email: String? ="",
                var money: Double? = 0.00
) {
    @Exclude
    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "uid" to id,
            "name" to name,
            "email" to email,
            "money" to money
        )
    }
}
```

Home Fragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    val userId = mAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid
    getMoney() //function call here
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    btnTopUp.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(activity, TopUpActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    ScanPayButton.setOnClickListener{
        val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionScanAndPay()
        Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
    }

    btn_generate.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, GenerateActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    btn_capture.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, ScanQRActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

} //button declaration

fun getMoney(){
    val userId = mAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .child("Users").child(userId)
        .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError){
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val user = p0.getValue(user::class.java)
                //MoneyView.text = user?.money.toString()
                user?.run {(user(id, name, email, money))
                    MoneyView.text = money.toString()
                }
            }

        })
}//FUNCTION TO RETRIEVE DATA FROM FIRBASE AND DISPLAY IN A TEXT VIEW called MoneyView

}
```

**UPDATES**

After adding `Log.e("TAG", p0.getMessage())` in the `override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError)`, this is the logcat output.

[image: logcat picture]

After adding `Log.d("TAG", user?.name)` in the `override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)`, this is the logcat output.

[image: logcat picture 2]

[logcat picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNlmT.png)

> ANSWER

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmGzr.png)

Comment: What's wrong with the shared code? Do you have an error? Does `Log.d("TAG", p0.getMessage())` print something n the logcat?

Comment: Hi Alex Mamo, where i should add this code ?

Comment: Inside `onCancelled()` function. Do you have any output?

Comment: I will edit the post right now with a logcat picture!

Comment: There's no error there. Filter the results using **TAG**.

Comment: Well... the result is empty.... no answer related to TAG...

Comment: But if you try to log inside `onDataChange()` using `Log.d("TAG", user.name)` is something printed out?

Comment: I already edit the post again in UPDATES section, perhaps you can check it out.... Well from here I see no errors printed out.... :(

Comment: Is your `onDataChange()` even called?

Comment: I guess yes... if no, how to call it ?

Comment: "I guess". Try it your self. If it is not called it means you have no internet connection.

Comment: Well... it is connected with internet as I can log in and log out with Firebase Authentication...

Comment: Add a single log statement inside `onDataChange` is something printed out?

Comment: I have tried with my own phone too... nothing printed out .haha

Comment: You don't have internet connection.

Comment: Ok... so uhm.. I just check the Firebase tools in Android Studio, both Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database are connected. So any idea on how to connect to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

> ANSWER

Okay... I had solve this question on my own... JUST REPLACE THE FOLLOWING CODE IN **fun getMoney()**

Just click the image and u can get the answer....

[ANSWER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPlcl.png)